# How to request permission again when user Edited permission with MVC4 OAuthWebSecurity?

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-login

In C# ASP.NET MVC 4 I use `OAuthWebSecurity` to login as Facebook.
I require `Email` among few others. But `Email` is the **most** important part and without it the application should **not** continue.

As you know, the 1st image is the request. But in this step user can **Edit** the permissions.
[image]

And change the `Email` before continue like this 2nd image:
[image]

Here is the problem; once user **Disabled** the `Email` option, I cannot **re-request** the 1st image on the `C# MVC4` side. It always bypasses and comes back **without** the email.

How can I request again and **display the 1st image** when the `Email` is disabled?

Also, if you must know how I do the Facebook login, I used the code here https://github.com/tapanila/MVCScopedClient/blob/master/Source/MVCScopedClients/FacebookScopedClient.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `auth=rerequest` solved the problem.

```
public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
        {
            string url = baseUrl + _appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=" + scope + "&auth_type=rerequest";
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
```